# ProcessStartInfo not calling WinForm EXE

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, exe

When I run my application in localhost, it fires off the EXE. I loaded the web app into IIS 6, which resides on the real server, and all I get is the web page but the Winform EXE is never executed or launched. Am I missing something in my code below?

Winform code:

```
    //SQL section for returning images
    #region "Images Query"

    ImageQuery = "SELECT isn AS isn ";
    ImageQuery += "FROM bc_bcc_document (NOLOCK) ";
    ImageQuery += "WHERE barcode_id = ? ";

    DataTable Imagetable = new DataTable();
    Imagetable.Columns.Add("ISN", typeof(Int32));
    DataRow Imagerows;

    //fills table with Images information
    OdbcCommand comd = new OdbcCommand(ImageQuery);

    string conne = "Dsn=XXXX; uid=XXXXX; pwd=XXXXXX";

    using (OdbcConnection connected = new OdbcConnection(conne))
    {
        comd.Connection = connected;
        connected.Open();

        comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("barcode_id", txtBarcode.Text);

        OdbcDataReader readar = comd.ExecuteReader();

        while (readar.Read())
        {
            isn = Convert.ToInt32(readar["isn"].ToString().TrimEnd());
            Imagerows = Imagetable.NewRow();
            Imagerows["ISN"] = isn;
        }
        readar.Close();
```

Web App Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ImageView2
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var proc = new Process
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = false,
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
                {
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    FileName = @"C:\ImageViewer\ImageView.exe",
                    Arguments = Request.QueryString["DKT_ID"].ToString()
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The winform exe will get started on Server side not on client side

Comment: possibly a permissions issue, website running under a different user account for IIS

Comment: @Zeeshan is right it will get started on the server side but it needs the permission to be run on server.

Comment: @Zeeshan so is what I am doing not going to work? just kind of crazy that it works on the localhost but not when put on the server side?

Comment: @Iqbal any idea of exactly what type of permissions need to be set?

Comment: if you want to run the winform exe on client side then its not going to work. if you want to run the exe on server then right click on winform exe. go to properties and security tab and then add the user under which ISS is running and then give it the permission to execute the exe..

Comment: yes @clerktech right click on the exe file on the server select properties go to Security tab add ISS_USERS give read/write access save it. But be sure your web application is running under ISS_USERS otherwise change the ISS_USERS with the user which runs your web application

Comment: @Iqbal the EXE currently sits on the local C:/ of the user's computer, not on the server. using your previous instructions, how do I add an EXE to IIS since it isn't web based?

Comment: Then you can not do that. In this case you can achieve same functionality if you create an OCX, install the OCX on client machine, call your OCX from you web application. These are few link to think about this. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4953/Simple-way-to-expose-a-NET-WinForm-control-as-an-A

Comment: @Iqbal I put the exe anywhere I want but local C:\ is where I currently have it. All I am trying to do it get the DKT_ID from a querystring and pass it a winform. Any other ideas?

Comment: @clerktech as you may notice from all comments, it is not possible to execute exe on client machine through web application. It does not matter what exe is doing. If you can put the exe on your server mean on the same machine where your web application is. Then you can execute it after security setting. You might notice during development it will run perfectly on your developer machine. Remember here the exe and web application are at same machine so no issue. Otherwise you have to choose OCX option.

Comment: @Iqbal got it. Thank you for the help. Yes, I can put the EXE on same server as the web application. Just have to figure out the Security part now with that.